# limit the number of results using NSDictionary keysOfEntriesPassingTest:

Tags: objective-c

I'm declaring a variable just to limit the number of results filtering a NSDictionary. Is there any other way to do this avoiding the extra variable?

My code:

```
//Pick one part from each item
__block int partsCounter = 0;
NSSet *itemsParts = [self.deckDictionary keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

    //filter with itemRef value
    CollectiblePart* part = (CollectiblePart*)obj;
    if([candidatesSet containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: part.itemRef]]){

        if(partsCounter < quantity)
        {
            partsCounter++;
            return YES;
        }else{
            //stop the filtering
            return (*stop = NO);
        }
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}];
```

Comment: It might be a bit slicker to add your own category method `-[NSDictionary(KZAdditions) kz_firstKeys:ofEntriesPassingTest:]` which internally handles counting the number of entries which have passed the test so far.

Comment: Yeah I think so. At least with the category I can hide this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's the best way to do it.

While the method allows the block to be exited mid way through, it has no idea why it would have to do that, and as such doesn't accommodate any aids in doing so.

In your semantics, you need to keep a tally to keep track if something exceeds a particular threshold. Having a variable to do that makes sense.